Converting basic update logic from a table to a view in Snowflake
I'm working on converting something that's currently in a table in snowflake into a view. One of the big issues I've run into is that the code I was provided to build the table uses the SQL UPDATE command to alter one of the columns, and I can't see any equivalent for how you can update a view.
The way the code currently works is that it builds the table, and only assigns levels 1 and 3, then uses the following code to set the levels as 2:
UPDATE person_levels AS a
SET person_level = 2
FROM person_levels AS b
WHERE a.person_parent_id = b.person_id
AND b.intermediary_level = 1
AND a.intermediary_level = 3

Using dummy data - I've got a single table with information on people and their parents, as well as a column detailing their level (1 for no parents, 2 for a parent, 3 for a parent who has a parent; will only ever go as far as 3 levels and each will only ever have one parent per level). Examples from below: Person ID 1 is a level 1 and has no parents, Person ID 8 is a level 2 and has Person 1 as a parent, Person ID 12 is a level 3 and has person 8 as a parent (who in turn has person 1). Tables below showing data before and after the update:
Data before the update:



Person ID
Person Parent ID
Person Level




1
1
1


2
1
3


3
2
3


4
4
1


5
5
1


6
4
3


7
4
3


8
1
3


9
1
3


10
2
3


11
5
3


12
8
3


13
13
1



Data after the update:



Person ID
Person Parent ID
Person Level




1
1
1


2
1
2


3
2
3


4
4
1


5
5
1


6
4
2


7
4
2


8
1
2


9
1
2


10
2
3


11
5
2


12
8
3


13
13
1



What I've currently got is a couple of CTEs joined/unioned appropriately to pull the pieces together. However, I'm not 100% confident in it, and I'm not sure whether there's any issues around performance/best practices/edge cases.
--Gives just the level 2 people, and hard codes their level as 2
level_2_people AS (
SELECT
        a.person_id,
        a.person_parent_id,
        2 AS person_level
FROM person_levels AS a
INNER JOIN person_levels AS b
ON a.parent_person_id = b.person_id
AND b.intermediary_level = 1
AND a.intermediary_level = 3),

--Gives just the level 1 and 3 people
level_13_people AS (
SELECT
        a.person_id,
        a.person_parent_id,
        a.person_level
FROM person_levels AS a
LEFT JOIN level_2_people AS l2
ON a.person_id = l2.person_id
AND l2.person_id IS NULL)

--Union the two data sets together
SELECT * FROM level_13_people
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM level_2_people

When I do:
SELECT * FROM person_levels
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM person_levels_v2

Between the two different methods, I get no results, and there's the same number of rows between the two, so it seems like they're the same. But I want to get a proper sense check before I go downstream and start changing everything else that this affects.
Happy to take any suggestions on any issues that may arise from doing things like this if there are any, thankfully it's not too much data and currently runs in a few seconds on the live data so I don't think performance is going to be a major issue but
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Please don't link to images - add data to your question as editable text, formatted as tables
